# How to make a first letter capital in C#

Tags: c#

How can the first letter in a text be set to capital?

Example:

```
it is a text.  = It is a text.
```

Comment: Can the string be something like `"99c waffles"` and you want to get `"99c Waffles"`? That is, what is your definition of "first letter"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make first letter of a string upper case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135317/make-first-letter-of-a-string-upper-case)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
public static string ToUpperFirstLetter(this string source)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
        return string.Empty;
    // convert to char array of the string
    char[] letters = source.ToCharArray();
    // upper case the first char
    letters[0] = char.ToUpper(letters[0]);
    // return the array made of the new char array
    return new string(letters);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do the `source.ToCharArray()`. A string is already a char array and can be indexed with just `source[0]`.

Comment: @Alastair, strings are immutable but char arrays aren't.

Comment: @Jacob, Oooh yeah. Shows how dead my brain is on a Friday afternoon  :/

Comment: Can I suggest you to write `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source)) return source;` instead of `string.Empty`? :D

Comment: And also renaming the method from `ToUpperFirstLetter` to `ToUpperFirstCharacter` which is a more relevant name :)

Comment: I know its old but just curious, why say "this string source" rather than "string source"?

Comment: @MiscellaneousUser That is because it is an extension method. Lookup C# extension methods.

Answer (score 45):

It'll be something like this:

```
// precondition: before must not be an empty string

String after = before.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + before.Substring(1);
```

Comment: @Danny: let's discuss your comment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474578/what-is-the-performance-of-substring-in-net

Comment: .NET is also slow. C++ or assembler is much faster. Does that mean we need to drop .NET and move to faster languages?

Comment: @Danny: Substring makes the code simple. I prefer to write simple code first, and then optimize with more complicated code *only where necessary*.

Answer (score 20):

polygenelubricants' answer is fine for most cases, but you potentially need to think about cultural issues. Do you want this capitalized in a culture-invariant way, in the current culture, or a specific culture? It can make a big difference in Turkey, for example. So you may want to consider:

```
CultureInfo culture = ...;
text = char.ToUpper(text[0], culture) + text.Substring(1);
```

or if you prefer methods on `String`:

```
CultureInfo culture = ...;
text = text.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper(culture) + text.Substring(1);
```

where `culture` might be `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, or the current culture etc.

For more on this problem, see the [Turkey Test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html).

Comment: Consider about different CultrueInfos, as well as TextInfos.

Comment: tell me the most case when we need to import Microsoft.VisualBasic dll when we work on C#.net

Comment: Taking consideration "CultureInfo" has made the solution perfect... Thanks a lot also for Turkey Test :)

Answer (score 5):

I use this variant:

```
 private string FirstLetterCapital(string str)
        {
            return Char.ToUpper(str[0]) + str.Remove(0, 1);            
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are sure that `str` variable is valid (never an empty-string or null), try:

```cs
str = Char.ToUpper(str[0]) + str[1..];
```

<s>Unlike the other solutions that use Substring, this one does not do additional string allocations. This example basically concatenates `char` with `ReadOnlySpan<char>`</s>.

**UPDATE**

Actually `str[1..]` returns string. According to the documentation it uses internally Substring() to do that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1831

In order to make it allocation free, use the following line:

```cs
str = string.Concat(new ReadOnlySpan<char>(Char.ToUpper(str[0])), str.AsSpan()[1..]);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using C# then try this code:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.StrConv(sourceString, Microsoft.VisualBasic.vbProperCase)
```

Comment: This is ugly. If your using C#, why would you be importing/referencing the Visual Basic DLL?

Comment: @steven: You can use VB libraries from C#.

Comment: Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.StrConv("hello", VbStrConv.ProperCase);

Comment: It's wrong anyway. This capitalizes every word, not just the first. Here's the VB function in action [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcwxCsMwDEDRuT6FyGRDnUuEQocGChk6y4kGgZGLJZve3g3t9OEPr7M2zDGh8h6FLPa0j7GWo2WCu9taghVZfHCXpYiWTPOrstGDhfxm9ZzdT2zACghGH5unK/T0rOVNdUGlENxNDjilX//0GF8 "Visual Basic .NET (VBC) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

```
text = new String(
    new [] { char.ToUpper(text.First()) }
    .Concat(text.Skip(1))
    .ToArray()
);
```

Comment: @Jon Skeet - That was entirely my intent :)  I was actually wondering what the performance would be compared to the substring method above.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post, but I recently had this problem and solved it with the following method.

```
    private string capSentences(string str)
    {
        string s = "";

        if (str[str.Length - 1] == '.')
            str = str.Remove(str.Length - 1, 1);

        char[] delim = { '.' };

        string[] tokens = str.Split(delim);

        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
        {
            tokens[i] = tokens[i].Trim();

            tokens[i] = char.ToUpper(tokens[i][0]) + tokens[i].Substring(1);

            s += tokens[i] + ". ";
        } 

        return s;
    }
```

In the sample below clicking on the button executes this simple code `outBox.Text = capSentences(inBox.Text.Trim());` which pulls the text from the upper box and puts it in the lower box after the above method runs on it.

[image: Sample Program]

Answer (score 1):

Take the first letter out of the word and then extract it to the other string.

```
strFirstLetter = strWord.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper();
strFullWord = strFirstLetter + strWord.Substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static String UppercaseWords(String BadName)
    {
        String FullName = "";

        if (BadName != null)
        {
            String[] FullBadName = BadName.Split(' ');
            foreach (string Name in FullBadName)
            {
                String SmallName = "";
                if (Name.Length > 1)
                {
                    SmallName = char.ToUpper(Name[0]) + Name.Substring(1).ToLower();
                }
                else
                {
                    SmallName = Name.ToUpper();
                }
                FullName = FullName + " " + SmallName;
            }

        }
        FullName = FullName.Trim();
        FullName = FullName.TrimEnd();
        FullName = FullName.TrimStart();
        return FullName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this functions makes capital the first letter of all words in a string

```
public static string FormatSentence(string source)
    {
        var words = source.Split(' ').Select(t => t.ToCharArray()).ToList();
        words.ForEach(t =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++)
            {
                t[i] = i.Equals(0) ? char.ToUpper(t[i]) : char.ToLower(t[i]);
            }
        });
        return string.Join(" ", words.Select(t => new string(t)));;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "it is a text";
```

// first use the .Trim() method to get rid of all the unnecessary space at the begining and the end for exemple ("   This string   ".Trim() is gonna output "This string").

```
str = str.Trim();
```

`char theFirstLetter = str[0];` // this line is to take the first letter of the string at index 0.

`theFirstLetter.ToUpper();` // .ToTupper() methode to uppercase the firstletter.

`str = theFirstLetter + str.substring(1);` // we add the first letter that we uppercased and add the rest of the string by using the str.substring(1) (str.substring(1) to skip the first letter at index 0 and only print the letters from the index 1 to the last index.)
`Console.WriteLine(str);` // now it should output "It is a text"

Comment: I like the idea with triming.

Answer (score 0):

```
string Input = "    it is my text";

Input = Input.TrimStart();

//Create a char array
char[] Letters = Input.ToCharArray();

//Make first letter a capital one
string First = char.ToUpper(Letters[0]).ToString();

//Concatenate 
string Output = string.Concat(First,Input.Substring(1));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code snippet:

```
char nm[] = "this is a test";

if(char.IsLower(nm[0]))  nm[0] = char.ToUpper(nm[0]);

//print result: This is a test
```

Comment: char[] nm = "this is a test".ToCharArray(); will work