# Mathematica GraphPlot and the EdgeRenderingFunction

Tags: graph, wolfram-mathematica

While I'm waiting for the [sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795029/need-a-way-to-sort-a-100-gb-log-file-by-date) to finish, I would like to adjust a part of Mathematica graph I'm working on. The problem is that nodes are on top of edges, I wonder if there is a way to reverse that. In the image you can see that arrows are not showing proper...

I'm doing a `GraphPlot[]` with custom `VertexRenderingFunction` and `EdgeRenderingFunction` paramaters. It looks something like this:

[Where are the arrows? Can you see them? Did you take my arrows? http://img816.imageshack.us/img816/9703/graphbadarrows.png](http://img816.imageshack.us/img816/9703/graphbadarrows.png)

As you can see, it would be as they say *cool* if the arrows were on top of the nodes. Is there an easy way to *hax* it in?

Comment: That looks neat, can you share the code you wrote for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark's answer does exactly what you asked for -- and you could write your own function that automates the Reverse.

A less direct solution might be to just draw the arrow heads back from the end a little:

```
GraphPlot[Table[i -> Mod[3 i + 1, 9], {i, 0, 8}], 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({{White, Disk[#, 0.15]}, 
     Circle[#, 0.15]} &), DirectedEdges -> True, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Arrowheads[{{.05, .8}}], Red, 
     Arrow[#]} &)]
```

This would also reduce the congestion at the nodes.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if there is a way to do this directly with GraphPlot options or not but you could manipulate the Graphics object produced by GraphPlot directly.  For example, here's a graph whose features are similar to yours.

```
bg = GraphPlot[Table[i -> Mod[3 i + 1, 9],
  {i, 0, 8}], DirectedEdges -> True,
  VertexRenderingFunction -> (
  {{White, Disk[#, 0.15]}, Circle[#, 0.15]} &),
  EdgeRenderingFunction -> (Arrow[#1] &)]
```

You can examine the structure of the Graphics primitives and directives as follows:

```
  bg // InputForm
```

You can see that the arrows are placed down before the vertices.  Simply reverse this as follows.

```
  MapAt[Reverse, bg, {1, 1}]
```

Of course, your Graphics object will likely have a different structure.

Mark McClure

Comment: That looks great, I'll try that and report back!