# How can i sort large csv file without loading to memory

Tags: c#, file, sorting, csv

I have 20GB+ csv file like this:

```
**CallId,MessageNo,Information,Number** 
1000,1,a,2
99,2,bs,3
1000,3,g,4
66,2,a,3
20,16,3,b
1000,7,c,4
99,1,lz,4 
...
```

I must order this file by CallId and MessageNo as asc. (One way is load database->sort->export)

How can i sort this file without loading all lines to memory in c#? (like line by line using streamreader)

Do you know a library for solution?
i wait your advice,
thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use OS sort commands. Typically it's just

```
sort myfile
```

followed by some mystical switches. These commands typically work well with large files, and there are often options to specify temporary storage on other physical harddrives. See this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795029/need-a-way-to-sort-a-100-gb-log-file-by-date), and the Windows `sort` command ["man" page](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sort.mspx?mfr=true). Since Windows sort is not enough for your particular sorting problem, you may want to use [GNU coreutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)  which bring the power of linux `sort` to Windows.

### Solution

Here's what you need to do.

1. Download [GNU Coreutils Binaries ZIP](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/coreutils-bin-zip.php) and extract `sort.exe` from the bin folder to some folder on your machine, for example the folder where your to-be-sorted file is.
2. Download [GNU Coreutils Dependencies ZIP](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/coreutils-dep-zip.php) and extract both `.dll` files to the same folder as `sort.exe`

Now assuming that your file looks like this:

```
1000,1,a,2
99,2,bs,3
1000,3,g,4
66,2,a,3
20,16,3,b
1000,7,c,4
99,1,lz,4
```

you can write in the command prompt:

```
sort.exe yourfile.csv -t, -g
```

which would output:

```
20,16,3,b
66,2,a,3
99,1,lz,4
99,2,bs,3
1000,1,a,2
1000,3,g,4
1000,7,c,4
```

See [more command options here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort). If this is what you want, don't forget to provide an output file with the `-o` switch, like so:

```
sort.exe yourfile.csv -t, -g -o sorted.csv
```

Comment: In which OS sort command able to parse CSV file and sort by a particular feld?

Comment: To my knowledge Linux; I think Windows too.

Comment: I believe there is small possibility that developer asked C# question using Linux, anyway if you 100% sure regarding linux and not sure regarding Windows you should indicate this in your answer. This is my point of view.

Comment: Good point, but you can use Linux sort in window with a few pains.

Comment: I know you can sort a positional byte/column number, but What what if you want to sort the third field?  Are there switches to do that?

Comment: This is not really a portable pure C# way of solving the problem. I think the [external sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7361224/429091) answer points to a better more portable solution.

Answer (score 4):

This is a classical algorithm problem called [External Sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting).

> External sorting is required when the data being sorted do not fit
>   into the main memory of a computing device (usually RAM) and instead
>   they must reside in the slower external memory (usually a hard drive).
>   External sorting typically uses a sort-merge strategy. In the sorting
>   phase, chunks of data small enough to fit in main memory are read,
>   sorted, and written out to a temporary file. In the merge phase, the
>   sorted subfiles are combined into a single larger file

From `.NET Framework` point of view I would recommend to leverage `.NET 4` feature - [Memory Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) to project parts of the file in memory as separate views.

[Here is](http://code.google.com/p/externalsortinginjava/) an Java example of External Merge Sort, you should be able to adopt it to C# easily:

**EDIT:** Added usage example of the mentioned Java sample to demonstrate its simplicity

```
Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() 
{                         
  public int compare(String r1, String r2)
  {                                 
     return r1.compareTo(r2);
  }
};                 

List<File> l = sortInBatch(new File(inputfile), comparator);                
mergeSortedFiles(l, new File(outputfile), comparator);
```

Answer (score -3):

you should use python for this kind of tasks :)

have a look here for a similar, full working example:

[Python: How to read huge text file into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896674/python-how-to-read-huge-text-file-into-memory)

**EDIT:**

in that same answer there is a link useful in case your file is really way bigger than available amount of RAM: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/466302/

Comment: i cannot load 24GB+ file to memory (is memory issue)

Comment: Oguzh4n, read that answers, there is also a link to an article on how to do it when file much bigger than available RAM: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/466302/