# Capitalize sentence in C#

Tags: c#, string, char

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [How to make a first letter capital in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474254/how-to-make-a-first-letter-capital-in-c-sharp)

I am trying to capitalize the first word in a sentence. This is what I have, but it is not working.

```
char.ToUpper(sentence[0]) + sentence.Substring(1)
```

Comment: you mean the first letter of a sentence?

Comment: SOLVED- I solved it by doing the following. I needed it to be sentence[1] and substring(2) for some add reason.

    sentence = Char.ToUpper(sentence[1]) + sentence.Substring(2);

Comment: Perhaps you might have run `sentence = sentence.Trim();` on it first. There might have been a space before the first letter.

Answer (score 9):

[JaredPar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861792/capitalize-sentence-in-c-sharp/9861814#9861814) is right, but I'd also like to point you towards the [TextInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.aspx) class. ToTitleCase() will capitalize the first letter, and convert the remaining to lower-case.

```
        string s = "heLLo";
        var t = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
        s = t.ToTitleCase(s); // Prints "Hello"
```

Comment: You can do this without creating a new CultureInfo - `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s)`

Comment: This is not the case. TextInfo.ToTitleCase() converts the first letter *of every word* to an upper case character, not just the first letter of the string (sentence in this case), which is what the question is asking for.

Comment: see @Camille Sévigny comment.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're just trying to capitalize the first character of a `string` value.  If so then your code is just fine, but you need to assign the new string back into the `sentence` value.

```
sentence = char.ToUpper(sentence[0]) + sentence.Substring(1)
```

A `string` in .NET is immutable and hence every operation which changes the `string` produces a new value.  It won't change the original value in place.  So in order to see the result of the change, you must assign it into a variable.

Comment: I tried this but it still is the same result.

Comment: @user1072481 how are you using `sentence` then?  The above code should work just fine so it must be in the usage of the result